# How to add label in apex:pageBlockSectionItem

Tags: visualforce

How to add Label next to the inputText in pageblockSectionItem as shown in the screen shot, here is what I have done so far but I do not see any output `Hours` in the vf page.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Work"/>                  
     <apex:inputText value="{!totalHours}"  /> 
     <apex:facet name="header">Hours</apex:facet>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something with outputPanel, example below:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Work"/>                  
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:inputText value="{!totalHours}"/> 
        <apex:outputLabel value="Hours"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```